# Printing mutiple Doc files in c# using document.printout but it shows wierd behavior

Tags: c#, printing, office-interop

I am trying to print multiple (100 or more) word documents each with multiple pages one by one using document.printout method. All the documents need to remain in printer queue till pages are added. It works fine with few documents less than 50 but when tested with 80 or more documents having multiple pages then results gets inconsistent.

**I have tried following:**

Loop through all the docs one by one when loop ends then close the word com object. When printing is performed sometime it queues all the docs perfectly and spooling is also done successfully. Sometimes it queues the documents but spooling never ends and word instance also gets released. this causes documents to miss in printing.
Please confirm if I must need to keep on waiting till the spooling ends using wordApp.BackgroundPrintingStatus or spooling will complete once the document is sent from the application? As per my observation even if I release the word com object spooling gets completed but sometime it does not. Please suggest?
Below is the code snippet:

```
var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
try
{            
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            var _document = application.Documents.Open(fileName);
            try
            {                          
                object copies = "1";
                object pages = "";
                object range = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument;
                object items = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent;
                object pageType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages;
                object oTrue = true;
                object oFalse = false;
                object missing = Type.Missing;
                _document.PrintOut(ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue,
                            ref missing, ref oFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                       
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                _document.Close();
                _document = null;                           
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log(ex);
}
finally
{              
    application.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
    application = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code example that shows your current approach?

Comment: Code snipped added in the post

Answer (score 0):

[Document.printout()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-printout-method-word) expects the first parameter to be `True` if you want to put in background and continue adding documents. If you put `False`, the process will wait until the print file has been spooled to the printer queue.

```
object oBackground = false;
...
_document.PrintOut(ref oBackground, ref oFalse, ref range, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref items, ref copies, ref pages, ref pageType, ref oFalse, ref oTrue,
                        ref missing, ref oFalse, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Also, It would be better if you make the function without using the same variable for more than one parameter (like `oTrue`), so you can make single modifications without affecting more parameters:

```
 _document.PrintOut(opBackground , opAppend , opRange , opOutputFileName , opFrom , opTo , opItem , opCopies , opPages , opPageType , opPrintToFile , 
  opCollate , opFileName , opActivePrinterMacGX , opManualDuplexPrint , opPrintZoomColumn , opPrintZoomRow , opPrintZoomPaperWidth , opPrintZoomPaperHeight )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice Igor, it really helped. setting background property to false seems to be working but i was wondering about the possible exceptions with document.printout. what if a document fails to spool due to any reason? if  one document fails due to any reason, will other will continue? How to trace the printing failures? I have checked the documentation for the document.printout at MSDN but it is not showing any specific exceptions with this?